# Curl Failed: Failed to connect to [servername] port 80: Connection timed out

Tags: php, curl

The Following code is showing an error when I runs in server. But this code works in local host

```
public function send($url)
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

        $output=curl_exec($ch);
        /*curl_close($ch);
        echo $output;
        return $output;*/
if ($output === FALSE) {
   die("Curl Failed: " . curl_error($ch));
} else {
curl_close($ch);
   return $output;
}

}
```

showing following error

```
Curl Failed: Failed to connect to [servername] port 80: Connection timed out
```

please help me

Comment: Maybe some firewall?

Comment: in phpinfo allow_url_fopen  is on